# Full Text search on varbinary(max) column is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, filestream

I've searched every site, blog (even the answers here) but none seem to work. I created a db in SQL Server 2008 r2 (Fulltext search is activated and available for the created database), create a table (followed all the steps to create a table enabled for Filestream), created the catalog, the full text index.. and when I enter a simple test query, it returns nothing.Here i'll paste all the code I used for creating the database and everything else.

```
CREATE DATABASE FSTest

    ON PRIMARY(NAME = FSTest_data,
        FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

\FSTest_data.mdf'),

    FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = FSTest_fs,
        FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

\filestream')
LOG ON( NAME = FSTest_log,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

\FSTest_log.ldf')
GO

USE FSTest

CREATE TABLE dbo.Documentos
(
  Id [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Documento varchar(50),
  Extension varchar(10),
  Archivo varbinary(max) FILESTREAM NULL
)

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FSCatalog AS DEFAULT

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Documentos

(Documentos, Archivo TYPE COLUMN Extension)
KEY INDEX UQ__Document__3214EC061CF15040
ON FSCatalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

Now, I'll populate a row with a file from my computer

```
DECLARE @Arch as VARBINARY(MAX)
SELECT @Arch = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX))
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\cecar\inso.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x

INSERT INTO dbo.Documentos (Id, Documento, Extension, Archivo)
VALUES(NEWID(),'Ingenieria del Software','.doc',@Arch)
```

As for all of the instructions above they work, none of them give me any error messages. Still when I enter queries like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Documentos 
WHERE CONTAINS(Archivo, 'crisis')   //The word 'crisis' is contained in the file, I double checked..
```

Or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Documentos 
WHERE FREETEXT(Archivo, 'crisis')
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Documentoss 
WHERE CONTAINS(Archivo, '"crisis*"')
```

I get nothing.. the result is blank.. not even an empty row, nothing. I even thought it might be due to a long document name in the field 'Documento' so i entered a new value like 'inso' and the results are still the same. What am I doing wrong? And please do not give me some link to a Microsoft site, I just need an example on how to do this correctly so it works (I don't need to find documents by some word in its name, but by words inside it).

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Exactly the same problem. It works with one database and doesn't work with another. And there are no differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have not figured out the error in the above script yet, the statement to create the full text INDEX should read thus --

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Documentos

(Documento, Archivo TYPE COLUMN Extension)
KEY INDEX UQ__Document__3214EC061CF15040
ON FSCatalog
```

Where the first parameter should have been "Documento" (the column within the table) instead of "Documentos" (the table itself).